# El teclado de mi computadora no funciona

Tags: linux, teclado

El problema radica en que básicamente desde que actualice mi sistema operativo linux lite 5.4 con los comandos: `sudo apt update`  y `sudo apt upgrade` no he podido utilizar el teclado de mi computadora. Sin embargo si un teclado externo. He intentado reiniciando y también ejecutando  `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`. Pero nada funciona.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta no es sobre programacion no? hay un sitio particular para linux en la red

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación, tal como lo establece el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta parece más adecuada para [su].

Comment: @Nelcido Rafael Díaz Pérez, tienes que dar más especificaciones de tu ordenador. ¿Es una laptop o una computadora de escritorio? ¿qué marca es? ¿qué modelo es? ¿qué sistema tenía instalado cuando la adquiriste? ¿qué marca y modelo de teclado externo usaste? Como te mencionaron los compañeros del foro, necesitas más detalles para que te podamos ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.